# The portal is having issues getting authentication tokens for Microsoft_Azure_Compute, HubsExtension, fx

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When we login to https://portal.azure.com , it is showing this notification as "Experiencing authentication issues".We thought those notifications are coming due to an App Service/Api Services. But we have neither of them. How to get rid of these notifications?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9m5R.png)

Comment: same as here, still waiting for azure support to fix this